# If I divide one column of a matrix by another, do I get new "information"?

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis

Sorry in advance for my poor math terminology. Does dividing one column of a data-frame by another column give new "information" or help with classification?

I am collecting data on treadmill sessions. One of my columns contains "distance ran" and another contains "time ran". Intuitively, if I created another column for "average speed", I would not get new information but I also know that dividing one column by another isn't a valid matrix operation, so would creating another column for "average speed" help with classification?

Comment: What do you want to classify?

Comment: This question may be better suited for Cross Validation Stackexchange

Comment: Consider squaring each element of a column - here you do get a new column in a different direction. Notice that squaring is non linear (fpr ex,
 [1, 2] and [1, 4] point in two independent directions). This is precicely the reason you get new information. Similarly multiplying two columns can also give a new column in different independent direction..